# Deriving a clock_out of frequency 10 Hz with a counter and a clock_in of frequency 50 MHz in VHDL

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl

I did something like this but it doesn't work cause it's probably rubbish.

```vhdl
entity taktteiler is
    port ( clk : in std_logic;
           clock_out: out unsigned (22 downto 0);
end taktteiler;
  
architecture arch of taktteiler is
  
signal count: unsigned (22 downto 0);
signal tmp : std_logic := '0';
  
begin
  
process(clk)
begin
 if(clk'event and clk='1') then count <= count+1;
    if (count = "01001100010010110011111") then
    tmp <= NOT tmp;
    count <= "00000000000000000000000";
    end if;
 end if;
 end process;
clock_out <= tmp;

        
end arch;
```

Comment: **How** does it not work? It's easier to help you if you describe what the idea behind what you've built is, what it *should* be doing, and what it *is* doing instead. (Also, as developer: that's how I solve 90% of bugs in my own code, spelling these three thing out for myself.)

Comment: You can compare unsigned against integer, making the rollover test much easier to read and get right. (You may also need to reset count so that it starts at a defined value)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a ton of examples for clock dividers out there, but here's one served for you

```
ENTITY clockdivider IS
  PORT(
    clk_i           : IN     std_logic;
    rst_i           : IN     std_logic;
    clk_out         : OUT    std_logic
);
END clockdivider;

ARCHITECTURE behavioural OF clockdivider IS
  SIGNAL counter : unsigned(23 DOWNTO 0);
  SIGNAL clk_int : std_logic;
BEGIN

  clk_out <= clk_int;

  clk_div : PROCESS(clk_i,rst_i)
  BEGIN
      
   IF rst_i = '1' THEN
      counter <= to_unsigned(5_000_000-2, counter'LENGTH);
      clk_int <= '0';

    ELSIF rising_edge(clk_i) THEN
        IF counter(counter'LEFT) = '1' THEN
            clk_int <= NOT(clk_int);
            counter <= to_unsigned(5_000_000-2, counter'LENGTH);
        ELSE
            counter <= counter - 1;
        END IF;
    END IF;
  END PROCESS clk_div;
  
END ARCHITECTURE behavioural;
```

By counting down instead of up and check for the overflow you can save a lot of comparison. In your case you only have to compare the left most bit instead of all 23 bits. What is strange with your implementation (and probably wrong) is the output type, I guess `clock_out` should be of type `std_logic`.
Anyway I prefer to not make steps bigger than 1000 with a single clock divider but have multiple dividers cascaded. In your case it would probably make sense to go to 1MHz -> 1Khz -> 10Hz, but that's just personal preference of course.